# Writing JSON files in ElectronJS (asar)

Tags: node.js, json, electron, fs, electron-packager

### Problem

`FrameWork - ElectronJS`

My program uses `.json` files to save the user entered data. In development environment those files are written perfectly, however after packaging it with `electron-packager` the JSON files are no longer written, which completely makes my program invalid.

I used mostly those `JSON` files to write my program, so removing them completely will be again doing the program from scratch. Is there a way to make the program write the `JSON` files in client PC as it does in dev-environment.

### Sample Program

This is just a sample program, but all of my code is in this format.

```
//JavaScript 

//This Javascript catches user inputs and send them to jsonWriter function


document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  var userData = document.getElementById('username').value
  var acctData = document.getElementById('account').value

  var formData = {
    username: userData,
    account: acctData
  }; // create JS object

  await writer.jsonLC(formData);
});


// This is my json Writer function

async function jsonForAuth(data){

    let element = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '\\data\\auth.json', element) 

//All my directory for 'fs' are written in such format with a '__dirname'

}

module.exports.jsonLC = jsonForAuth;

// All of this works perfectly on dev-environment (VS-Code)
```

Now I package it with `electron-packager`

```
// Here is my package.json for reference

{
  "name": "electron_app",
  "productName": "Test App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "asar": "^3.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "keytar": "^6.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "puppeteer-core": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.2",
    "electron-packager": "^15.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron_app --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=assets/img/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Test App\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The packaging codes are exactly same as [This guide here](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/).

### Conclusion

Now after packaging the app and some script which don't require `json files` works fine. But Now the `sample program` above is rendered useless as json files are not created anymore.

** How to make this work? **

`Note: I have NOT used ipcRenderer() anywhere in my program.`

### Update

I found out that `asar` is read-only file.

So is there a way to change the location of my json save location maybe to Local/Appdata ?

Thank you and sorry if explanation is too big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, writing to the application location is not a good idea and often forbidden. It should be sufficient to use the appdata folder which is usually used for application settings etc.

[`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) is the function you are looking for.

Then do something like:

```js
fs.writeFileSync(app.getPath("appData") + "/auth.json", element);
```

Or maybe even better, using [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths):

```js
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(app.getPath("appData"), "auth.json"), element);
```

Comment: Thank you, for this. However I seem to have run into another issue, ```let {app} = require('electron')```....Again  ```let test = app.getPath("appData")``` then I console log test. However, this gives me this error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined```

Comment: @SubhankarChowdhury Have you resolved the issue by now, since you accepted the answer? Some possibilities: are you running in the main process? Are you sure the `app` variable that you got from `require` is still in scope in the function (is it the same file, etc)? Any chance you redefined the variable? Does `console.log(app)` work?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I replaced the ```app.getPath()``` with ```appdata-path module``` I found on the internet, Now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @AurelBílý, I have an issue using the `app.getPath()` object. I have a js file that gets called from events based on the interaction with the HTML, but then when it is loaded the *app* object is **undefined**. The  **const {app} = require('electron')** is used at the top of the file, and is also used in 'main.js' (a different file). How can this be resolved?